# Ошибка при добавлении в List

Tags: java, android, массивы, list, getview

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста решение такой проблемы:

Есть классы:

```
class EntityAction{}
class FirstAction extends EntityAction{}
class SecondAction extends EntityAction{}

class Model{
    public List<? extends EntityAction> actions;
}
```

Вот когда я в одном из методов пытаюсь сделать так:

```
Model m = new Model();
FirstAction a = new FirstAction();
m.actions.add(a);
```

Я получаю такую ошибку:
[image]

Как мне создать такой список, в котором могут быть разные объекты унаследованные от одного общего?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures

Comment: Ваша декларация

    public List<? extends EntityAction> actions;

означает: `actions` — список объектов _какого-то_ типа, производного от `EntityAction`. То есть `action` вполне может оказаться `List<SecondAction>` на самом деле, компилятор этого не знает.

Поэтому он и не даст вам положить в список экземпляр `FirstAction`.

---
С другой стороны, когда вы _получаете_ объект из `actions`, вы можете быть уверенным, что он имеет тип, производный от `EntityAction`, а значит, можете присвоить переменной этого типа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

оставь класс **Model** таким:

```
class Model
{
    public List<EntityAction> actions;
}
```

UPD
по поводу комментария как узнать тип

```
String str;
if (str instanceof String)
{
   // какой то код
}
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!
А подскажите пожалуйста, почему получается такая ошибка, ведь вроде бы эквивалентные вещи.

Comment: Теперь другая проблема - как просматривать этот список, ведь я не знаю какой тип ко мне прийдет...?

Comment: @ua6xh: Вот почему ошибка: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1292147/276994

Comment: @ua6xh добавил код как узнать тип объекта

Comment: роман-захаров - Угу, видел! Спасибо!

@VladD Спасибо!

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api